# How to change Doctrine final query with Api Platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

With Api Platform and for one entity, I want to change the final query.

I already know `QueryCollectionExtensionInterface` / `QueryItemExtensionInterface` ([documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extensions/)) but this only allows access to the first table (`root`) and not the joins :

```
final class ConversationExtension implements QueryCollectionExtensionInterface, QueryItemExtensionInterface
{

    public function applyToCollection(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface
        $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        string $operationName = null
    ): void {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    public function applyToItem(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        QueryNameGeneratorInterface
        $queryNameGenerator,
        string $resourceClass,
        array $identifiers,
        string $operationName = null,
        array $context = []
    ): void {
        $this->addWhere($queryBuilder, $resourceClass);
    }

    private function addWhere(
        QueryBuilder $queryBuilder,
        string $resourceClass
    ): void {
        if (Conversation::class !== $resourceClass) {
            return;
        }

        dump($queryBuilder); // only root
        ...
```

**Maybe** [filters](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/) are a lead but I can't seem to figure out how to get to the QueryBuilder for all get (collection and item).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. We had to change the priority to < `-8` to access the whole query :

```
App\Extension\ConversationExtension:
    tags:
        - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.collection, priority: -9 }
        - { name: api_platform.doctrine.orm.query_extension.item, priority: -9 }
```